# How do I use Kotlin methods in XML files?

Tags: xml, kotlin, button, frontend, backend

Im trying to use methods from Kotlin in Android Studio..
Its a bit hard to understand.
How can I use the method there in activitys?
Is there a another option to use without buttons?

For exmample:

**Kotlin method:**

```
    val galatasaray =  Team("Galatasaray",100)
            val fenerbahce = Team("Fenerbahce",60)
            fun spielen(){
              var winner = ""
                if(galatasaray.rating>fenerbahce.rating)  winner= galatasaray.name
                
                if(galatasaray.rating<fenerbahce.rating) winner= fenerbahce.name
                println(winner)
            }

//________________________________________________________

    class zweitesBild : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_zweites_bild)
    
            val actionBar = supportActionBar
    
            actionBar!!.title = "üben"
    
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    
            var buttonGS : Button = findViewById(R.id.ButtonGS)
            var buttonFB : Button = findViewById(R.id.ButtonFB)
            val win = "Galatasaray gewinnt"
    
    
            buttonGS.setOnClickListener{
                
               spielen()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a another option to use without buttons?*

If you are asking if a different type of view could be used to call your method then the answer is yes. You can set a listener to any class that extends **View**

You can also call your method inside an Activity lifecycle callback such as onCreate().

If you can elaborate on what it is you are looking to achieve, I can try an give you a better answer.